# Is it possible to use variables in cloud-config

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto, cloud-init, salt-stack

When using [cloud init's](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) #cloud-config to create configuration files, how would I go about using variables to populate values?

In my specific case I'd like to autostart EC2 instances as preconfigured salt minions. [Example of salt minion cloud config](https://github.com/number5/cloud-init/blob/master/doc/examples/cloud-config-salt-minion.txt)

Say I'd like to get the specific EC2 instances id and set that as the salt minion's id.

How would I go about it setting the value dynamically for each instance?

Answer (score 4):

in boot command `bootcmd` can have environment variable `$INSTANCE_ID`, you can save it for later usage. see http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html#run-commands-on-first-boot

I for example do like below

```
#cloud-config
bootcmd:
  - echo $INSTANCE_ID > /hello.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest I've seen to configurable variables is [Instance Metadata].(https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/instancedata.html#)

It says you can use:

> - userdata provided at instance creation

You can use data created in `/run/cloud-init/instance-data.json`.

You can use import this [instance data](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/instancedata.html#using-instance-data) using [Jinja templates](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/) in your YAML cloud-config to pull in this data:

> ```yaml
> ## template: jinja
> #cloud-config
> runcmd:
>     - echo 'EC2 public hostname allocated to instance: {{
>       ds.meta_data.public_hostname }}' > /tmp/instance_metadata
>     - echo 'EC2 availability zone: {{ v1.availability_zone }}' >>
>       /tmp/instance_metadata
>     - curl -X POST -d '{"hostname": "{{ds.meta_data.public_hostname }}",
>       "availability-zone": "{{ v1.availability_zone }}"}'
>       https://example.com
> ```

But I'm not exactly sure how you create the `/run/cloud-init/instance-data.json` file.

This [CoreOS issue](https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/801) suggests that if you put variables into `/etc/environment` then you can use those.

I know for example that there are a few variables used such as `$MIRROR` `$RELEASE`, `$INSTANCE_ID` for the phone_home module.

Comment: `cloud-init` populates the `/run/cloud-init/instance-data.json` file in order to unify the data provided from the various cloud providers. The `v1` entries are the safest to use, since they are where cloud-init collects common data, and the keys are guaranteed to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try the ec2metadata tool (just queries the EC2 metadata). Say put the following in your instances userdata:

```
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2metadata/ec2-metadata
chmod u+x ec2-metadata
# The following gives you the instance id and you can pass it to your salt minion config
ec2-metadata -i
```

More info on the ec2-metadata script [here](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1825)